# How to declare in a super POM the exclusions of an artifact when the artifact version is imported from a BOM

Tags: maven

I am using a BOM to declare the version of common artifacts across my projects.

I am importing the BOM in the `dependencyManagement` section of a super POM in a project with several submodules, like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybom</artifactId>
            <version>bomversion</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The objective is that children of this super POM will not have to declare the version of the modules they need. This works fine.

However, I also would like to being able to specify in my super pom that certain dependencies should be imported with exclusions, like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>artefactgroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The problem with this is that somehow the version is not recognized from the imported BOM in `myartifact`. Is that the expected behavior?

Which is the best way to declare exclusions in my super POM so the version can is taken from the BOM?

If I do not declare the exclusion in the super POM but in each child that requires `myartifact` it works, but the same exclusion declarations are spreaded everywhere in my project, which is far from being a good idea.

Comment: You can declare a dependency on slf4j-log4j12 with scope provided.